# How to create a JFrame Array?

Tags: arrays, vector, jframe

I would like to create an Array where each index will contain a JFrame. The number of slots depends on the user so I cannot simply do JFrame[] array = new JFrame[x]; as I do not know what x will be.

Is there an alternative way of creating a JFrame array. I've looked into vectors but couldn't get them working.

Comment: Can you post the Vector code that did not work? Someone might be able to help you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use something like:

```
List<JFrame> frames = new ArrayList<JFrame>();
frames.add(frame1);
frames.add(frame2);
...
...
```

An ArrayList is similar to a Vector, except it's methods are not synchronized. So unless you need the collection to be synchronized, an ArrayList is a better choice.

I don't understand what you mean by you couldn't get Vector's working. Why couldn't you get them to work?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Array use Arraylist. Arrarylist is more dynamic, for example:

```
Arraylist<JFrame> jFrameList = new ArrayList<JFrame>();

JFramme frame1 = new JFrame(...);
JFramme frame2 = new JFrame(...);
....
....
....

jFrameList.add(frame1);
jFrameList.add(frame2);
....
....
```